# How to re-create a JPEG file compressed by Android within a Java server

Tags: java, android, image-processing

What I am attempting to do is to convert a JPEG image from an Android app, send it across to a Java app (e.g. a server) and then convert it back to a JPEG file.

I know how to do these parts individually; i.e.
 - JPEG to byte[] conversion in Android using [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) and [BitMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) classes
 - conversion from a byte[] created in Java side (using [ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)) back into a JPEG class.

My question is how to re-create the JPEG in the Java side if the byte[] created by the Android app contains compressed data (e.g. created using `BitMap#compress` method). The only knowledge shared between Android and Java side is that the content will be a JPEG file 
(and can pass in info about a common compression algorithm if both libraries/APIs support it).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why would you want to recreate a jpg if you already have it ? BTW it doesnt matter where the file came from as this not the important part of the q...

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the compress() step if possible. JPEGs are already compressed. Otherwise you are going to need a BitMapFactory implementation on the Java side.